# Getting "Request contains an invalid argument." when calling googleapis projects.jobs.create

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to trigger a batch dataflow job via API so I'm trying to get it working in the API explorer tool [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/create). Unfortunately, the docs do not specify what the required parameters are, so I took a few stabs, but I can't get anything but this response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

The payload needs to be this [Job](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs?authuser=1#Job), but that doc is an exhaustive list of the Job properties of an already triggered job. Nonetheless, I took a stab:

```
{
    "projectId": "my-project",
    "location": "us-central1",
    "name": "some-random-name",
    "type": "JOB_TYPE_BATCH"
}
```

But I can't get the api explorer to return anything helpful.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 2):

The jobs.create API isn't designed to be used in this way - instead, create a templated Dataflow pipeline using the [Apache Beam SDK](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/beam-overview/) and run your job via the API with the [templates.create API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.templates/create).

Comment: Darn. I'm using reads from BigQuery and when using a template I get a [NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718323/apache-beam-with-dataflow-nullpointer-when-reading-from-bigquery/45083493#45083493). I might need to go back to the drawing board.